# Not able to push docker images to gitlab.com

Tags: docker, gitlab

I am building the docker image myself in my local PC and I am trying to push the image to GitLab Docker images repository but for some reason it does not work. I have created a personal access token with all permissions enabled, and logged in successfully using terminal. Sometimes when I try to push I get this error

```
Get "https://registry.gitlab.com/v2/": net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)
```

Some other times it goes a step further and pushes all layers (*in this step it takes a long time to finish and retries a couple of times to upload all layers*) but at the last step it gives an error message as below

```
Head "https://registry.gitlab.com/v2/xxx/yyy/blobs/sha256:xxx": dial tcp xx.xxx....:443: connect: connection refused`.
```

The image size is about 300MB tops and my internet speed is very good to fail for such small files. Does anybody know what might be the issue or how to trace it ?

Comment: Look on https://status.gitlab.com/ in times of trouble. Yesterday was a day with problems

Comment: Are you able to reproduce this issue still? If so, can you describe the exact steps to reproduce? Otherwise, I think it's reasonable to assume this was caused by the service outage mentioned by @AlexYu -- particularly since you mentioned the issue seems intermittent. (in which case, the question should probably be closed as not reproducible)

Comment: @sytech tried today and works fine, its a bit slow but most likely to be expected, will write back in case it continue. thanks